# In Microsoft Graph API, what filters are supported in people search query?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft graph provides a `people` query that can receive `$search` url parameter e.g.
`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/people/?$search="topic: work"`

- what search parameters are supported in the `people` query?
- what is the exact meaning of the `topic` filter?

Comment: In many of the other APIs, it is listed which properties support $filter. E.g. for user resources (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/user), some properties' descriptions say "Supports $filter." It would be nice if the Person resource docs also had this information.

Answer (score 1):

The [$search](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search) parameter searches across the `displayName` and `emailAddress` properties of a `person`.

> Searches on people occur on both the `displayName` and `emailAddress` properties of the person resource. Searches implement a fuzzy matching algorithm. They will return results based on an exact match and also on inferences about the intent of the search.

The `topic:` attempts to match people who are interested in a given topic by looking through the user's mail history. If you're emailing with someone about avocados then `topic:avocado` would surface that person.

> You can also perform searches for people who are interested in a particular topic. Searches are performed based on inferences derived from the user's mail conversations. .

Comment: can you explain what is the exact definition of a topic?

Comment: Topics themselves are not pre-defined, they are inferred using machine learning based on your conversation history. In other words, there isn't a pre-set list of "topics".

Comment: what is the difference between a topic and a phrase?
Is a topic like a syntactic entity or is it something more business oriented?
For instance, will "windows" the glass be different from "Windows" the OS

Comment: Topics are basically key phrases, you can read about a similar API at https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c6. As for "windows", it depends if your an IT shop or a replacement window company.

Comment: Why do you call it topic?
Is there a better communication channel to learn more about topics?

Answer (score 1):

"Topics" are just words that have been used most by users in email conversations. Microsoft extracts such words and creates an index for this data to facilitate fuzzy searches.
A search like the following:
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people/?$search="topic:windows"
is a fuzzy search in this topic data index. Topics in this data are context free, so a search for "windows" can include instances that mean the Windows operating system, an opening in a building wall, or other definitions.